# Can a passive USB Hub power an external soundcard and a bluetooth receiver?

Tags: usb, power, sound-card, usb-hub

[This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IRVQ0F8) is the soundcard I would be using and [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YA8U2BU) is the bluetooth receiver I want to power. I want to use a USB 2.0 Passive Hub (Power to the Hub comes from the connected port). Will a USB 2.0 port deliver enough power to the hub or do I need to use an USB 3.0 port or even an external power source?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "passive hub". There are "self-powered" hubs (powered from AC wall adapter), and "bus-powered hubs", who receive power from host port.

In theory, a bus-powered hub must report itself to a host system as such, and the system is supposed then to police the delivery of power to peripheral USB devices that a user might plug in. The bus-powered hub is not supposed to take too much power from host port (500mA/900mA limit), and the total must be fairly split between downstream ports of this hub.

Each bus-powered USB device has an information on how much power it will consume. Roughly devices fall into two categories, "low-power devices" (100mA or less), and "high-powered" (above 100mA). The policy of USB host is to determine the required power a device needs during initial stage of device enumeration. In case of "bus-powered" hub the rule is to reject devices that report their operating power above 100mA.

In theory, if a hub is able to get a power from DC jack but a user forgot to plug it into AC adapter, the hub must detect this, and change its descriptors to reflect this change. As result, all high-power devices who were working fine with AC adapter would stop working when the hub gets power from upstream port.

Obviously, this behavior will cause major customer confusion and disappointment. So, in practice, the world-wide industry invented a "work-around" by violating USB specifications and making hubs that do not report the change in power source. As result of this little "lie", the USB host will allow any device to be connected and go full power, which sometimes causes problems with power to USB devices as HDD enclosures.

Therefore, the answer to posted question depends whether (a) if the hub is truly USB compliant (which is likely not), and (b) whether the devices are high or low power. I would guess that both audio and BT dongles are low-power devices, so regardless of the kind of hub there should be no problem in this setup.